# When i make my screen smaller my website formats doesnt fit

Tags: html, css

i am making a website when i am om full screen the website looks good but when i am making the screen smaller the divs come out etc.

Here is a printscreen of it:
[image: Printscreen]

How do i fix this?
This is the HTML and CSS im using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Jari Rengeling</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">

            <img alt="wood" src="../Images/wood.png" id="wood">

                <div id="menu">
                    <span id="naam">Jari Rengeling</span>
                    <ul id="nav1">
                        <li class="li1"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="li1"><a href="overmij.html">Over mij</a></li>
                        <li class="li1"><a href="ervaringen.html">Ervaringen</a></li>
                        <li class="li1"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            <div id="headertext">
                <h1 class="space">Welkom</h1>
                <p class="space" id="headerp">Mijn naam is Jari Rengeling, ik ben een beginnend Applicatieontwikkelaar. Neem gerust een kijkje op mijn eigen portfolio.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">

            <div id="navigatie">
                <h2 id="h22">Navigatie</h2>
                    <ul id="ul2">
                        <li class="li2"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="li2"><a href="overmij.html">Over mij</a></li>
                        <li class="li2"><a href="ervaringen.html">Ervaringen</a></li>
                        <li class="li2"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="projecten">
                <h2 id="h21">Projecten</h2>
                    <div id="project1"></div>
                    <div id="project2"></div>
                        <p>Geen huidge projecten...</p>
            </div>

            <div id="socialmedia">
                <h2 id="h23">Sociale Media</h2>
                    <img alt="facebook" src="../Images/facebook.png" id="facebook" class="miniaturen">
                    <img alt="twitter" src="../Images/twitter.png" id="twitter" class="miniaturen">
            </div>

            <div id="contact">
                <h2 id="h24">Contact</h2>
                <p>Klik hier om mijn contact gegevens te bekijken!</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body 
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(154, 135, 100, 1.0);
    width: auto;
}

#menu
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgba(154, 135, 100, 0.80);
}

#nav1
{
    margin: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 400px;
}

.li1
{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-family: Champagne;
    color: white;
}

#wood
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}

#naam
{
    font-family: Champagne;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 400px;
}

.space
{
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Caviar;
}

#headerp
{
    max-width: 480px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#headertext h1
{
    font-size: 50px;
}

#headertext
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 400px;
    margin-top: 240px;
}

#footer
{
    background-color: rgba(154, 135, 100, 0.80);
    height: 210px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 700px;
}

#h21
{
    font-family: Caviar;
    margin-left: 400px;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    max-width: 230px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#project1
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.15);
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

#project2
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 530px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.15);
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

p
{
    font-family: Caviar;
    color: #ebebeb;
}

#projecten p
{
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    position: absolute;
}

#projecten
{
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

#navigatie
{
    margin-left: 400px;
    position: absolute;
}

.li2
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

#ul2 
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: Caviar;
    color: #ebebeb;
}

#h22
{
    font-family: Caviar;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0px;
}

a:hover
{
    color: black;
}

#h23
{
    font-family: Caviar;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0px;
}

#socialmedia
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 900px;
    top: -56px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 214px;
}

.miniaturen
{
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#contact
{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 1200px;
    top: 802px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 100px;
}

#h24
{
    font-family: Caviar;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    margin: 0px;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: Champagne;
}
```

Comment: All your margins and paddings and heights are in hard pixels (`400px`, etc). If you layout with `%` units, it will fit in all resolutions. However you need to use media queries (`@media` as @thewbmstr said) to make bulletproof in all resolutions.

Comment: Research responsive design and frameworks like Bootstrap

Comment: css media queries can be used to fit in small screens and devices 
ref link http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: The practice of creating a website which can adapt to multiple screensizes is called Responsive Design. There main way to achieve this is by using media queries (@media). I suggest you have a look at CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap or Materialize which can make this process very simple.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude is there a trick to change all pixels to percentages?

Comment: No, simply the sum of all horizontal percentages must not be more than 100%. Example, a div with 50% of width, 20% of padding and 5% of margin will occupy 100% of the available space. There's no trick, only manual calculations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule in css known as `@media` rule.
`@media` is used for creating responsive webpage.

example of `@media` rule :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <style>
                    body {
                        background-color: lightblue;
                    }

                    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
                        body {
                            background-color: lightgreen;
                        }
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>

                <h1>Resize the browser window to see the effect!</h1>
                <p>The media query will only apply if the media type is screen and the viewport is 480px wide or wider.</p>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your CSS code, I noticed you are almost always using `pixels` as a measure. You shouldn't do that unless you know exactly the size of the screen were your website will be open. Otherwise, using `percentages` is always a good thing. You can control the style like with pixels and when you resize, since everything has it's size according their parent elements, everything will resize.

I changed a bit of your CSS and HTML code for you to see it. It's not perfect but you can understand the power of using percentages instead of pixels (:

http://jsbin.com/tacayaweya/edit?html,css,output

You could use `@media` queries (just like it was said here) to control the style your website based on the screen size. The example of @Advaith is a good example of how to use it.

As also mentioned in the comments, using frameworks like Bootstrap can help you with the design of your website.